# php regex how to remove duplicate strings

Tags: php, regex

here is a long string like"abc,adbc,abcf,abc,adbc,abcf"

I want to use regex to remove the duplicate strings which are seperated by comma

the following is my codes, but the result is not what I expect.

```
$a='abc,adbc,abcf,abc,adbc,abcf';
$b=preg_replace('/(,[^,]+,)(?=.*?\1)/',',',','.$a.',');
echo $b;
```

output:,adbc,abc,adbc,abcf,

It should be : ,abc,adbc,abcf,

please point my problem. thanks.

Comment: maybe you can convert the $a into an array then compare the array to remove duplicate strings

Answer (score 3):

Here I am sharing simple php logic instead regex

```
$a='abc,adbc,abcf,abc,adbc,abcf';

$pieces = explode(",", $a);
$unique_values = array_unique($pieces);
$string = implode(",", $unique_values);
```

Comment: thanks @SureshKamrushi, can we use a simple regex to solve it?

Answer (score 0):

Here is positive lookahead base attempt on regex based solution to OP's problem.

```
$arr = array('ball ball code', 'abcabc bde bde', 'awycodeawy');
foreach($arr as $str)
   echo "'$str' => '" . preg_replace('/(\w{2,})(?=.*?\\1)\W*/', '', $str) ."'\n";
```

OUTPUT

```
'ball ball code' => 'ball code'
'abcabc bde bde' => 'abc bde'
'awycodeawy' => 'codeawy'
```

As you can for the input 'awycodeawy' it makes it to 'codeawy' instead of 'awycode'. The reason is that it is possible to find a variable length lookahead something which is not possible for lookbehind.

Comment: thanks@rajinevitable . if $str='abc adbc abcf abc adbc abcf', it will output "adabcf", supposing a more complicated string, including number or special charactors. like '123abc-90'. what can we do.

Answer (score 0):

You can also try

```
echo implode(",", array_unique(preg_split(",", $yourLongString)));
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this....

```
$string='abc,adbc,abcf,abc,adbc,abcf';
$exp = explode(",", $string);
$arr = array_unique($exp);
$output=implode(',', $arr);
```